# Setting text to fit the size of a UILabel and centre in SWIFT

Tags: swift, uiview, uilabel

I'm trying to set text to fit the size of a `UILabel` and also be centred. I am doing this programmatically. This is what it looks like currently:

[image]

As you can see, the text is going off the screen and is also not centred.

This is my code:

```
let questions = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac faucibus tellus."

questionsLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(10, 10, questionsView.frame.size.width - 20, 80))
questionsLabel.text = questions
questionsLabel.font = UIFont(name: Font.FuturaMedium, size: 25)
questionsLabel.sizeToFit()
questionsLabel.numberOfLines = 0
questionsLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
questionsView.addSubview(questionsLabel)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
questionsLabel.sizeToFit()
```

Makes the frame fit the size of the text. What you are looking for is:

```
questionsLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

This changes the font size to fit the width of the label. (However, do note that it will only downsize the font.)

```
questionsLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
```

Centers the text within the label.frame. So if you do the above. And make sure the label is centered, and it's width is correct. You shouldn't have to do anything else to center the text.

Swift 3:

```
questionsLabel.textAlignment = .center
```

Comment: `UILabel.sizeToFit()` doesn't work in `UITableView`'s cell

Comment: nor in UICollectionView cell